# Overriding GCM permission package prefix with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle Android project that has 4 product flavors (each has it's own unique package name). The `build.gradle` file is prity much straightforward:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // All dependencies here
    // ...
}

android {
    // Usual stuff goes here

    productFlavors {
        flav1 {
            packageName 'com.company.flav1'
            versionName calcVersion()
        }

        flav2 {
            packageName 'com.company.flav2'
            versionName calcVersion()
        }

        flav3 {
            packageName 'com.company.flav3'
            versionName calcVersion()
        }

        flav4 {
            packageName 'com.company.flav4'
            versionName calcVersion()
        }
    }

    // Other configurations
    // ...
}
```

Everything goes fine, and the required resources are merged, e.t.c. Now I am trying to implement a Push Notification feature using GCM. And according to the documentation, I must declare a permission for my app, like this:

```
<permission android:name="com.company.flav.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.company.flav.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

But I'm using a single manifest file, for all 4 applications (they differ only in application resources and some settings, that are put in the assets folder).

So my question is: How can I override these permissions for every product flavor?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I've used:

```
<permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

in the Android manifest - this appears to be resolved correctly.

Answer (score 14):

You can use some sort of inheritance AndroidManifest.

```
The following rules are used when dealing with all the sourcesets used to build a single APK:

 - All source code (src/*/java) are used together as multiple folders generating a single output.
 - *Manifests are all merged together into a single manifest. This allows Product Flavors to have different components and/or permissions, similarly to Build Types.*
 - All resources (Android res and assets) are used using overlay priority where the Build Type overrides the Product Flavor, which overrides the main sourceSet.
 - Each Build Variant generates its own R class (or other generated source code) from the resources. Nothing is shared between variants.
```

code:

```
  productFlavors {
        flav1 {
            packageName 'com.company.flav1'
            versionName calcVersion()
        }

        flav2 {
            packageName 'com.company.flav2'
            versionName calcVersion()
        }

        flav3 {
            packageName 'com.company.flav3'
            versionName calcVersion()
        }

        flav4 {
            packageName 'com.company.flav4'
            versionName calcVersion()
        }
    }

  sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aild.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        flav1 {
            manifest.srcFile 'flavor1/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }

        flav2 {
            manifest.srcFile 'flavor2/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }

        ...
    }
```

Where `flavor1` and `flavor2` are folders in root project folder.

In `flavor1/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.sample.someapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<permission android:name="com.company.flav1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.company.flav1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />  

</manifest>
```

In `flavor2/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.sample.someapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<permission android:name="com.company.flav2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.company.flav2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />  

</manifest>
```

And in root `AndroidManifest` everything else.

Comment: I must be missing out on something: what is the point of the android plugin's packageName configuration support in DSL if one still has to create multiple "hardcoded" manifest files for each flavor?

Answer (score 3):

The AndroidManifest.xml now merges correctly as of gradle 1.11, using the default settings.

Comment: does this mean that the sourceSet configuration is not needed anymore?

Comment: correct, I am not using any sourceSet info in my gradle.build file.

Comment: What happens if you install more than one flavor on the same device? Will each flavor get their own push notifications?

Comment: You will need to make sure you use a different sender id for each flavor, I do this by specifying the sender id in a flavor specific strings.xml.