# GCM not registering when changing package name with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin

In my regular build gcm works fine, but when I use flavors to change the com name things stop working.  My IntentService is never being initialized.  How should I set up my manifest files so that this happens?

- I have added them to the developer console.
- I am using gradle com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'

I get the logs

```
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ GCM IntentService class: com.sample.app.dev.GCMIntentService
V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Acquiring wakelock
```

and then nothing.  My custom IntentService class never gets initialized and my registrationId stays empty.  My current implementation is similar to the one here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334397/198034

How should I set up my manifest to get gradle 0.11.+ flavors to work with gcm?

Below is a manifest in one of my flavors, I have more code in the main manifest (all needed permissions, etc), but nothing else dealing with gcm.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.app"
    android:versionCode="45"
    android:versionName="0.6.5" >

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <permission android:name="com.sample.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sample.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="${packageName}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your manifest

Comment: I didn't post it because I've tried all sorts of different configurations, and my manifest is pretty big.  But I will add the important bits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
<permission android:name="com.sample.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.sample.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

...

```
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.sample.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

in my manifest and mybroadcastReceiver

...

```
   public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver
   {
    @Override
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context)
    {
        return GCMIntentService.class.getName();
    }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where you used the product flavors in your solution...care to explain it? And, which flavor does this manifest belong in?

Comment: This solved the issue. @wsgeorge, The default Android library GCMBroadcastReceiver sends its broadcast to the GCMIntentService at a single package location, which is changed by each flavor and cannot be reached. When you subclass the broadcast receiver and specifies a custom class name, the broadcast is redirected to the correct class every time.

Answer (score 0):

From your manifest it looks like your app's package name is `com.sample.app`, which is consistent with your `permission.C2D_MESSAGE` definition. Your receiver's intent filter's category says `${packageName}`. Hopefully that gets translated to `com.sample.app` too, as it should.

Other than that, your log posted above shows that your intent service is expected to be at `com.sample.app.dev.GCMIntentService`. That's a different package.

You seem to be using the old deprecated GCM client library, in which `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver` expects the intent service to be called `GCMIntentService` and be located in the main package of the app :

```
/**
 * Gets the default class name of the intent service that will handle GCM
 * messages.
 */
static final String getDefaultIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
    String className = context.getPackageName() +
            DEFAULT_INTENT_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME;
    return className;
}
```

Your manifest declares the intent service class to be in the main package of your app :

`<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />`

All these things don't add up. Either your app's package name is `com.sample.app.dev` or `com.sample.app`. If it's the former, the manifest you posted is incorrect. If it's the latter, there is no reason for the broadcast receiver to expect the intent service class to be `com.sample.app.dev.GCMIntentService`.

Comment: Gradle handles package name changes in the manifest, I'm unsure of how it does this and I don't know how to view the generated manifest.  It's possible that it switches out all instances of the package name with the flavor packagename.