# Android GCM with product flavors

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-cloud-messaging, android-productflavors

I have GCM sample android gradle project. Its worked well, when I add 2 flavors a push notification stopped to work. My compilation manifest (it's taken from `app\build\intermediates\manifests\ex\debug`)  file is below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.flavor.app"
    <uses-permission android:name="com.flavor.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.flavor.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.flavor.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.ex.app.GCMIntentService" />
        <service
            android:name="com.ex.app.AppLocationService"
            class=".AppLocationService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name=".AppLocationService"
                    android:value=".AppLocationService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

What should I do to fix this problem? Please help.

**UPD1.** I am using gradle v.0.12+. i think my final manifest file looks good,  GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this); - without errors, but GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(this) always false. =(

**UPD2.** My first flavor project with original package name (as project in main branch) works well, but second flavor with changed package doesn't work (registrationId for push is still empty), but in manifest file all permitions are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution in this post [GCM not registering when changing package name with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174320/gcm-not-registering-when-changing-package-name-with-gradle). I just override BroadcastReceiver, if anyone can explain why it helpes please tell me.

Comment: check my response for a simpler solution

Comment: it didn't help last time, it works with overrided BroadcastReceiver in pair

Answer (score 38):

Simpy use the `${applicationId}` alias like this

```
<permission android:name=            "${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel= "signature" />
<uses-permission android:name=       "${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name=       "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

And for the corresponding receiver use this

```
    <receiver
        android:name = "com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.GCMReceiver"
        android:permission = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>

            <category android:name = "${applicationId}"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: @Gorets this one works for me, and I think it is a direct answer... you should try this instead and mark it as answer

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thank you :)

Comment: And how should we handle the receivers?

Comment: in flovers we have same project id and server key right for both flovers