# How do you set up your AndroidManifest for GCM when having multiple build types?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I've followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21006552/507339) to set up an android project with multiple build types. Since I'm supporting GCM in my project, I run into trouble when running the debug build. The manifest is only set up to receiver for the production build:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

The thing is when I compile for debug, my ApplicationId is `com.myapp.debug` instead. Is there any way to parameterize this particular manifest section?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333696/overriding-gcm-permission-package-prefix-with-gradle?rq=1